# Location of parity blockchain in Windows

Tags: parity

Where is the blockchain used by parity located in Windows? I get a crash during the database migration after a parity upgrade and would like to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: it is under `C:\Users\<my-usernname>\.parity`. There was another one under `C:\Users\<my-username>\AppData\Roaming\.parity` that confused me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the roaming stuff in `C:\Users\<my-username>\AppData\Roaming\Parity`

And the executables in "C:\Program Files\Parity Technologies\Parity"