# Parity chain data location in Windows 10

Tags: mist, parity

I first installed Mist, which downloaded 23GB of blockchain data, and the deleted all the blockchain data and mist-related files.

Then, I installed the parity on my windows 10 machine. Within a 10 min, parity shows that chain data is synced. However, I cannot find any chain data on my PC. The remaining storage has not been changed. I cannot find the folders mentioned in this answer:
[Location of parity blockchain in Windows](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8941/location-of-parity-blockchain-in-windows)

I could send and receive ETH with parity. So, I guess the parity client does not download any chain data.

I was wondering whether my guess is correct or not. If it is getting the blockchain from the web, would it be safer option than the Mist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%LOCALAPPDATA%/Parity/Ethereum/chains/<network>`

It was moved to this location from the original location of `%APPDATA%/*` because `AppData/Roaming` (which is where `%APPDATA%` points) is synced over the network on login/logout while `AppData/Local` (where `%LOCALAPPDATA%` points) is not.

Comment: Is that location configurable? I don't want to fill up the system SSD.

Comment: Yes.  The parity wiki has information on how to redirect the various folders.  It does require a bit of manual work, it currently isn't possible to change via UI.